# External IP addres confirm

Tags: c#, ip

I'm trying to do an application that allows the entrance of someone in some account, but only one IP address can access that account, but when i do this code;

```
IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
if (IPHost.AddressList[0].ToString() == "94.132.170.228")
{
    Process.Start("C:/Users/xlysa/Desktop/Coding/CSGO Cheat Client + Injector by Lysander12/ConfFiles/windows.exe");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
} catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something gone bad!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It says erros because the program is no recognising my IP address! And yes, I'm sure that this is my IP address!

Can someone help me with this pls?

Comment: Have you tried to check what is under ```IPHost.AddressList[0].ToString()``` ?

Comment: Time to learn how to use the debugger. Probably you will notice that your code doesn't get the external ip address of your PC but the local one.

Comment: why do you have a `catch{}` without a `try{}` is this a typo

Comment: There is no place like home :) 127.0.0.1

Comment: "Have you tried to check what is under IPHost.AddressList[0].ToString() ? – Gaskoin"

Yes I do, and it's my IP address!
If after the IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()); I put console.write("IPHost"); It gives me MY IP address, but the "if statement" is not working as it should do...

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access your external IP from inside the network like that in C#. If you were hosting that on a server you'd be able to allow connections that originate from that IP (like whitelisting). But the best bet is to link your program up with [WhatIsMyIP](https://www.whatismyip.com/) and have it return the IP to you.

Personally, I'd go with a whitelist at firewall level, rather than application level. This means the firewall will restrict access rather than relying on code to do it for you. Questions like "What if it has a bug, or a zero-day that can be exploited?" are the type of questions you need to think about when you decide if access control should be done through code when there are already other well-made solutions out there. If it was my choice, I'd be using what I already know works and requires least effort

Comment: I have already tried the thing of WhatIsMyIP but i doesn't work too

Comment: The problem is that i want to make different accounts for the program, and which one can be acessed only by the defined IP addresses.

The account A wil be only accessible by IP address X
And the account B will be accessible by the IP addresses Y and Z

(for exaple)

Comment: Would it not be easier to just define user accounts for the program? You can link each user account to an IP address as a claim so that you can only log in from a specific location with a specific account. I don't see any reason to do this when you could just create general user accounts for each location and use roles or access segregation controls